# Save List Texts of data using flutter_secure_storage... is it possible?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) in my Flutter app...

I am saving data as a key-value pair with it. It takes a value of type String like this:

```
 await storage.write(key: 'currentUserID', value: 'userid');
```

and I am reading it like this:

```
currentUserID = (await storage.read(key: 'currentUserID'));
```

but `currentUserID` it just a String!

What if I have a List of Strings... is there any way to save them all in the storage?

What I need is like if I have:

```
List<String> listViewerBuilderString = ['a1','a2','a3']
```

What I need to do is like call the array to = the Saved array in the storage something like this:

```
List<String> listViewerBuilderString = (await storage.read(key: 'listOfItems'));
```

Is this even possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved by using JSON serialization like so:

```
void myFunction() async {
  const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  List<String> listViewerBuilderString = ['a1','a2','a3'];
  await storage.write(key: 'listOfItems', value: jsonEncode(listViewerBuilderString));
  String? stringOfItems = await storage.read(key: 'listOfItems');
  List<dynamic> listOfItems = jsonDecode(stringOfItems!);
  print(listOfItems);    
}
```